# Add-AzureRmVhd throwing synchronization errors

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation

I am trying to upload a VHD using the following command in a azure automation powershell workflow:

```
Add-AzureRmVhd -DefaultProfile $Profile -LocalFilePath $Filepath-Destination $DestUri-ResourceGroupName $RGName
```

and I keep getting the following error:

*`Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.`*

Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: have you tried manually uploading vhd to blob? if so, was the manual operation successful?

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the -DefaultProfile parameter and it started working. I am still not sure why it was giving the error with the DefaultProfile parameter